# React.js - How to update properties/props/state of dynamic child components from a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm learning React right now, and I'm trying to develop my own package. I came across this problem.

So I have a Parent Component that would control children components, but these children are not explicitly defined. They are accessible with `props.children`.

This could be an easy example to explain my situation. I don't have a defined number of Child components as children of Parent component.

```
function Parent(props) {
  functionCalledEverySecond() {
    for (let child of props.children) {
      // Increment width by 1 like:
      // child.props.width  += 1
    }
  }

  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

function Child(props) {
  return <div style={{ width: props.width }}></div>;
}
```

How would I go by to attacking this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `React.Children API` ([react children API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)). You can map all children, clone every one with `React.cloneElement(child, {props})` ([react clone element](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)) and after that set new props.

There is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lalande-9vitp?file=/src/index.js) and the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-flexbox-grid";

function Parent(props) {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      width: parseInt(child.props.width) * 2 + "px"
    });
  });
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: props.width, height: "10px", background: "black" }}
    ></div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child width={"10px"} />
        <Child width={"20px"} />
        <Child width={"30px"} />
        <Child width={"40px"} />
        <Child width={"50px"} />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!